# C: strcat() terminates program without error

Tags: c, fgets, c-strings, string-literals, strcat

I'm writing C-Code on a windows machine. This is my first serious C program so I might not know a lot of the vocabulary.

I'm trying to write a program that reads the characters from a text file and puts them in a string.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
# define MAXCHAR 10

char* load_html(char* filename) {
  FILE *file;

  file = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (file == NULL) {
    printf("File not found %s", filename);
    return NULL;
  }

  char str[MAXCHAR];
  char* html= "";

  while (fgets(str, MAXCHAR, file) != NULL) {
    printf(str);
    //strcat(html, str);
  }

  return html;
}

int main() {
  char* filename = "load_html.c";
  load_html(filename);

  return 0;
}
```

When I compile (`gcc -o load_html.exe .\load_html.c`) and run this piece of code it runs perfectly fine and prints the source code of this program to the console. However if I uncomment strcat

```
  while (fgets(str, MAXCHAR, file) != NULL) {
    printf(str);
    strcat(html, str);
  }
```

the program will read the first line of the file, pause for 1 to 2 seconds and then exit without an error.

What exactly is going on here? I feel like I'm missing something very important.

Comment: Please, note that `strcat()` has to get a buffer of sufficient size as first argument. It doesn't allocate on its own.

Comment: `printf(str);`..you sure?

Comment: @SouravGhosh It compiles. What would be best practice here?

Comment: Maybe you should read a book before playing whac a mole with the compiler. I assure you that it would be much easier

Comment: @PixelRayn: Welcome to StackOverflow! "It compiles" is **not** an indicator for a well-formed, correct, or safe program, **especially** not with C/C++. Not even if you **do** have all possible compiler warnings enabled, which I am certain you have not. Using a user-defined string as first parameter for `printf()` is a potential security leak, because that format string is *interpreted*, i.e. can be made to "do things". Use `puts( str )` or `printf( "%s", str )`, both of which will print `str` verbatim (`puts()` will add a newline at the end, which may or may not be what you want).

Comment: Thanks @DevSolar :)
I'll change that. As I said, I'm learning and learning by doing has always been the most efficient way for me to learn a new language. Haven't dealt with anything as low-level as C before though.

Comment: Well, you should learn by doing, sure. But you need to have a good book as a guide to tell you about the pitfalls and "thinking in C".

Comment: C and C++ are of a different breed than many other, more "modern" languages. They eschew lots of error checking and safety features for raw control over bits & bytes. This makes them very efficient and versatile, but this comes at a cost: They are very much **not** languages you should approach by trial & error. There is a world of difference between "this compiles and apparently does what I want" and "this is actually good C/C++".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this declaration

```
char* html= "";
```

you declared a pointer to the string literal `""`.

Then in this statement

```
strcat(html, str);
```

you are trying to change the pointed string literal.

However you may not change a string literal. According to the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

So if you want to accumulate strings read from a file you need to define an enough large character array.

For example

```
char html[MAXCHAR * MAXCHAR];
html[0] = '\0';
```

But in this case one more problem arises because you may not return a local   array from a function that will not be alive after exiting the function.

So a more flexible and correct approach is to reallocate a character array dynamically in the while loop for each new string read from the file.

Something like

```
char *htmp = calloc( 1, sizeof( char ) );
size_t n = 1;

while (fgets(str, MAXCHAR, file) != NULL) {
    printf(str);

    n += strlen( str );

    char *tmp = realloc( html, n );

    if ( tmp == NULL ) break;

    html = tmp;

    strcat(html, str);
}

// ...

return html;
```

And in main you should free the allocated memory when the array is not required anymore.

```
free( html );
```

Comment: `char html[MAXCHAR] * MAXCHAR]];`
This line seems to be faulty. Did you mean
`char html[MAXCHAR * MAXCHAR];`?

Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Okay thank you :)
However with the first approach the compiler throws a warning:

`warning: returning 'char *' from a function with return type 'char' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`
`return html;`
`^~~~`
`.\load_html.c:25:10: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]`

I think the return type is wrong but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: @PixelRayn If you declared a character array like for example char html[SomeValue];  then you may not return it from the function because it will not alive after exiting the function. Use the approach with the dynamic memory reallocation I showed in my answer.   As for the error with the returning type it seems you declared the return type as char instead of char *.

Answer (score 2):

`html` is a pointer to a string literal, these can't be changed (and are normaly stored in a read-only section of memory), which is what `strcat` tries to do, invoking [undefined behavior](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3) in the process.

Even if that wasn't the case, `html` is clearly too small to take anything else as it only has space for 1 character.

It should be:

```
char html[SIZE] = "";
```

Where `SIZE` must be big enough to take all of the concatenated strings.

In this case you have a problem as you are returning `html`, if it's not a pointer it will be a local variable who's lifetime will expire as the function returns. You can work this out by:

---

1. Keeping `html` as a pointer and allocating memory to it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
//...
char *html = malloc(SIZE);
```

You then need to `free(html)` when you're done with it.

---

2. Or passing a pointer to char as argument of the function:

```
void load_html(char* filename, char* html){ //void return type

    //remove declaration of html
    //do not return anything
}
```

And in main:

```
int main(){

    char* filename = "load_html.c";
    char html[size]; //buffer to store the concatenated string
    load_html(filename, html); //the string will be stored in the buffer you pass as an argument

}
```

I would prefer this second option as you don't need to allocate memory which is a more expensive method and forces you to manage the memory manually.

---

`printf(str)` is also ill-formed, this function needs the format specifier to print formatted output:

```
printf("%s" str);
```

Or use simply `puts(str)`.

Answer (score 0):

`html` is a pointer to 1 byte of memory. That memory is read-only because it's a statically allocated string. `strcat` overwrites it, so is undefined behavior for two reasons: writing memory out of bounds, and writing to memory that is read-only.

Any weird behavior you see (eg: your program exiting early) may be caused by that.